# Stop FIREFOX from caching captcha

Tags: php, firefox, caching, captcha

So I have this form here: http://www.piataterenuri.info/register.php 
The problem is that Firefox caches the captcha image and after an incorect input, or a page refresh the captcha will show the old image instead of the curent one.

I've already placed:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

And also changed the captcha img src to

```
<?php $rand=microtime() * mktime(); echo "src=\"captcha.php?time=$rand\""; ?>
```

What else can I do to stop firefox from caching the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix this `Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Oct 2010 18:11:57 GMT`. Send the current time in the `Last-Modified` header.

Comment: Now who will tell us HOW to send current time in last modified header

Comment: header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . "GMT");

Answer (score 0):

force ffx to load the image after page was loaded via ajax